# Alphavantage API in Python - no Date on X axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, alpha-vantage

So some basic stuff - Running python 3.x (Jupyter Notebook) with Alpha Vantage

I'm running this simple code. It all works well, the only problem that I have is that it does not show me the date on the x axis. Anyone has any idea why is doing this?

```
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ts = TimeSeries(key='06VFCKNZ709V6XFG', output_format='pandas')
data, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol='MSFT',interval='1min', outputsize='full')
data['4. close'].plot()
plt.title('Intraday Times Series for the MSFT stock (1 min)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

So it needed this line in order to print out the dates

```
data.set_index( pd.to_datetime(data.index), inplace=True )
```

The problem right now is that it displays the time after the stock market closes. And the API does not have those dates. I'll keep posting the answer in case I find it.